# Is there a way to display a HSSFWorkbook Object in a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, apache-poi, poi-hssf

Is there a way to Display a HSSFWorkbook Object in a JSP page without having an output file in the server side?
In the code below I am providing the template file and the beans required for **net.sf.jxls.transformer.XLSTransformer.transformXLS(InputStream is, Map beanParams)** to return me a HSSFWorkbook object. I now need a way to use this object in a JSP without having to store the output file in the server side using OutputStream.

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(templateFileName));
HSSFWorkbook hm = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);
req.getSession().setAttribute("excelWorkBook",hm);
```

Comment: display it how - output an Excel file, or display it as HTML within the page?

Comment: Yes Matt, i must show it as an Excel file but I must not store the Excel file any where in the server side,I must directly deliver it to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks simple, write the HSSFWorkbook using the write method on your instance;

```
HSSFWorkbook#write(OutputStream)
```

where the output stream is the;

```
response.getOutputStream()
```

Youll probably want to do things like set the ContentType of the reponse as well as maybe some content dispostion attributes.

Comment: Hi Simon622, I used this step before but it threw me errors. My point is that I am exporting my HSSFWorkbook Object to the JSP page and I need to show the output of that object as an Excel spreadsheet without storing the resultant Excel file after HSSFWorkbook#write(OutputStream)
it at the server side.

Comment: Youll need to paste the error you are receiving when attempting to write the spreadsheet to the response, if we're to be able to help you further.